# React-native-ble-plx is it possible to send an image exery second

Tags: react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to dev an android app that can scan ble device, connect to one of them and then send an image every second or every 2 second to an RPI 3. The image would be a screenshot, resulting in some kind of screen mirroring with 1 images per seconds. I have an app that can scan ,detect and connect to my RPI with BLE, but i can't seem to find how to send files or images as i don't understand how the write functions works. I don't really understand the characteristics and services. I'd like to write the image in the /tmp directory of my RPI. Do any one of you have an example or could explain me how to do it ?

Comment: Quick question: Does your app has to use BLE? The bandwidth of BLE is designed for Low Energy application and not the fastest. I would suggest switching to Bluetooth Classic for you application

Comment: It doesn't have to but i didn't find any classic bluetooth librairies for react-native. If you have one that would be easy to use, i'll gladly try to use it

Comment: Bluetooth classic is sometimes called bluetooth serial: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-bluetooth-serial

Comment: Didn't know that, i'll give it a try then. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Do you happen by any chance to have a running application with this library i could use as an example ? So that i can learn from an concrete example ?

Comment: There is an example application on their github: https://github.com/rusel1989/react-native-bluetooth-serial I don't know if its running or what it's doing though

Comment: Bluetooth is not suitable for this kind of app. Under optimal conditions, Bluetooth Classic can achieve a data rate of 2 Mbps. That get's you about 0.5MB every 2 second, in the best case. That's insufficient for screenshots.

Comment: Yeah i'm kinda aware of that problem but this is for a uni project and i just need to show a working application even if is there is 1 image/2sec. I need it to work not to be efficient